# Installing iOS on VMware Workstation

Tags: ios, windows, virtualization

I have a Windows PC and VMware Workstation. I am trying to figure out a way to install iOS on it.

Is there is way to install iOS on VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  See relevant [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037623/running-osx-in-virtual-pc-in-a-windows-7-machine) discussion.

In short, you need to virtualize the ARM cpu, not an x86 model. Additionally, you'd need to virtualize the swipes and taps and whatnot, which would be quite the tall order.

Here's one project that's attempting to virtualize iOS on the QEMU platform: [IEMU](http://www.iemu.org/).

Comment: I don't see how the linked discussion is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

## xpadian

it is not for vmware,but it is work and it is the best ios 7 emulator.[image]

Comment: " iPadian is not a emulator so you can't run .ipa apps downloaded from iTunes, instead of that we create a custom App store where we put all the compatibles apps to run inside iPadian. " Apps have to be converted